# Drupal 7 - Webform 3 - How do you expose form results to Views Easily?

Tags: views, webforms

What is a good module to use to expose Webform 3.x results to views? I want to create a views page with links to each form submission so search engine spiders can crawl and index user submitted questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a page with links to each webform submission, you can just use Views itself; you don't need an extra module.  Add a new view.  Choose show *Content* of type *webform*.  Check the box for *Create a page*.  As the display format, I would recommend choosing the format you want and using *fields*; this will easily allow you to add links to the forms.

To be sure the search engines (Google, Bing, etc.) index your content, though, I wouldn't use this approach.  I would use the [XML Sitemap module.](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap)

Comment: This only creates a view list of all my webforms. i want to be able to select which fields or webform components to manipulate and show. since webform compenents aren't fields it won't show up in the fields dialog menu.

Comment: If you want to use webform components as fields, I suggest using Webform 4.x.  While it's still in alpha at the moment, it uses Field API instead of webform's custom component handling.  I know yo asked  for 3.x, but 4.x was a rewrite of 3.x specifically to handle this problem; I don't think there is a good solution for integrating with Views and 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Your only option,  really (short of upgrading to at least D7/Webforms 4.0,  or converting to real nodes -- see webform entity module):

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views

Limited,  but may accomplish your goal.